# Infinite tweening hue loop in AS3 with Tweener

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, tween, tweener

I'm trying to infinitely loop a bitmap all the way through the colour spectrum using AS3, [Tweener](http://code.google.com/p/tweener/) and its ColorShortcuts class. This doesn't loop back to  the function "tween1":

```
function tween1():void {
    Tweener.addTween(image, { _hue: 180, time:5, onComplete:tween2 } );
}

function tween2():void {
    Tweener.addTween(image, { _hue: -180, time:5, onComplete:tween1 } );
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested, but could you get away with:

```
function tween1():void {
    image._hue = -180;//you might need something like a colorMatrix here
    Tweener.addTween(image, { _hue: 180, time:5, onComplete:tween1 } );
}
```

I know there is no _hue by default, but I'm guessing you see what I mean.